# How to split swagger API documents by versions and groups in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an API which has separate swagger documents for each version.

Currently in project configuration I am iterating through ApiVersionDescription list and creating separate swagger document in following way:

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

foreach (var desc in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(
    desc.GroupName,
    new Info()
    {
        Title = "API" + description.ApiVersion,
        Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
    });
}

foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
{        
   options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", 
   description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
}
```

It creates documents v1, v2, v3 and so on based on attribute "ApiVersion" for controller classes

I would like to split each version to lets say 3 endpoints and for each endpoint it would have separate document.

In situation where API has versions v1 and v2 I would like to have documents like:

- V1 Endpoint 1
- V1 Endpoint 2
- V1 Endpoint 3
- V2 Endpoint 1
- V2 Endpoint 2
- V2 Endpoint 3

Is it possible?

Comment: check attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]`

Comment: I checked it, but is there way to iterate through it + through version name, so that each method would be assigned correctly?

Comment: check if https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/244 this thread helps, and do post the answer what worked for you, I have not encountered this scenario till now, but I would be interested to know!

Comment: For now I don't think there is a solution to this problem

Comment: Try below provided link. I think it will work for you. [Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181467/how-to-implement-api-versioning-and-swagger-document-dynamically/59182213#59182213)